# Weird issue with environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have this strange Issue with environment variables on my windows 7 system. Its been there for an year and I have had a work around but I need to solve it now:

I have an environment variable `JAVA_HOME` set as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\`. And in my `PATH` I have added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`.

But when I do `java -version` it prints `"1.7.0_11"` and when I do `javac -version` it prints as expected `1.6.0_39`

I do not know why `1.7.0_11` is printed for `java -version`. I have checked my `PATH` and have added JAVA_HOME only once. How can I know which env variable is responsible for using my `java.exe`? How do I avoid it?

Comment: I understand you mean %JAVA_HOME%\bin, not %JAVA_HOME\bin%

Comment: It was a typo. edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly a version of `java.exe` in `c:\Windows\System32`, which is likely to come earlier in your path than the part which refers to `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: How would `java.exe` end up in `System32`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I believe it's just part of the default installation on Windows.

Comment: Trying the installer, the default location was `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre7` , unless that was the location of a previous installation that the installer found.

Comment: Yes it was. But I wonder how did it ever go there. As far as I remember, it should never had happened. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: That's the overall location, but I believe java.exe is also copied into System32 as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, hopefully `%JAVA_HOME\bin%;` is a typo, but if not, it should be `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

For the rest - `java -version` is looking for your JRE, not your JDK.  `javac` is looking for the JDK.

Check to see if you have a JRE-related environment variable.  As well, check your path for any hard references to the Java 7 JRE.  Finally, look in C:\Windows\System32 and see if there is a `java.exe` there.

Answer (score 1):

`Java.exe` is installed on windows twice. The first location is where you expect it: under your `JAVA_HOME`. The second one is under `c:/windows`. Since this path always wins any other user defined path you are running java from here. If you want to hold several java environments and switch between them by changing your `JAVA_HOME` just remove `java.exe` from `c:/windows`.